# Knots with Fox tricoloring number $\mathrm{tri}(K)=27$

Tags: knot-theory

I would be very grateful if you help me to find such knots. Or to find a knot atlas, where this invariant is included. I tried to find, but did not succeed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was looking for the definition of tricoloring number of a knot on the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_n-coloring. But I didn't find the definition of number, can you give it to us? Thank you!

Comment: Here's a nice article, where you would find [link](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0608/0608172v1.pdf)

Comment: Ok, so the tricoloring number of a knot counts how many different tri-colorations you have on a knot (as defined on wikipedia). And it is always a power of 3. An example for k=3^1 is given by the trivial knot and an example for k=3^2 is given by the trefoil knot, as explained in the article you cited. We are looking for an example with k=3^3. I apologize for the repetition but I want to clarify the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, since an example of such a knot is pretty easy to find (see the square knot $3_1 # 3_1$ for example) I think your intent was to classify all the possible knots with such tricoloring number.